# How to ignore Email Address with Ipaddress in c#

Tags: c#, regex, validation, email

i am using the following Regular Expression to validate the Email Address, i am using server side Validations.

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

The above expression validating the email address perfectly, but it is not validating **test@192.123.12.1** type of email addresses.

i don't the email addresses with IP-Address as domain name to get validate test pass. i have googled but didn't found any helpful result.

Please help me. My question is : **test@192.123.12.1** should not pass the validate test.

Comment: replace `\w` with `[a-zA-Z]` to force only alphabets

Comment: @nu11p01n73R will it work for alpha-numeric?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R if i replace the "\w" with "[a-zA-Z]" it not accepting "name@mailinator.com" even

Comment: Just looking for alpha's won't work (what about kitty654@9mail.tld ?) Here's some reading I found very enlightening: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/

Comment: By the way here's Microsofts proposal to validate emails... http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/01escwtf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Try adding a look ahead `\w+([-+.']\w+)*@(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*`. [See  the demo](https://regex101.com/r/xU5sT8/3)

Comment: But be alarmed that you regex would alo accept anythilg like `foo@bar.anything.anydomine`

Comment: @nu11p01n73R +1 for the regex. Demo is quiet good.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R please add your comment in Answers section so that i can accept it and you will get rewad..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a look ahead following `@` so as to ensure that there is atleast 1 alphabet following `@`

```
/\w+([-+.']\w+)*@(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/
```

- `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` Positve look ahead. Checks if the `@` contiains an alphabet. If this match returns true, then proceeds with the remaining pattern. Else would discard the entire string.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xU5sT8/3)

**Test**

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@(?=.*[a-zA-Z])\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$");

Console.WriteLine( pattern.IsMatch("name@mailinator.com"));
=> True

Console.WriteLine( pattern.IsMatch("test@192.123.12.1"));
=> False
```